# Is there a better way to generate an isometric map grid in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, grid, coordinates, isometric

```
def map_grid(obj, startx, starty, map_size):
    grid = []
    for n in range(map_size[1]):
        startx -= 32
        starty += 16
        grid.append([[startx, starty]])
    for n in range(map_size[0]):
        startx = grid[n][0][0]
        starty = grid[n][0][1]
        for n in range(map_size[0]):
            startx += 32
            starty += 16
            grid[n].append([startx, starty])
    for n in range(map_size[1]):
        for m in range(map_size[0]):
            main_window.blit(obj.src, (grid[m][n][0], grid[m][n][1]))
```

Obj is the image to be displayed(In this case,  green tiles), startx & starty are the starting cartesian coordinates, map_size is the grid size in '(row, column)' format.

When I input mapsize as (10,10), I expected a 10x10 isometric map but instead i am getting this,
[adbnormal map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOugT.png)
which is 11x9 with an extra 10th coordinate in the first of the 11 rows.(Please refer to image for better understanding.)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize this isn't in python, but the way I do this in Swift is as below (should be easy to map to python, I've made it a little pseudo-codey)

```
for y in 0..<mapHeight {
    for x in 0..<mapWidth {
        drawTile(x: (y * tileWidth) - (x * tileWidth), y: (y * tileHeight) + (x * tileHeight))
    }
}
```

Thanks for you question though, it helped me simplify my own algorithm!